# Illegal character in MoviesController.cs in MVC Movie tutorial

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I am following the Microsoft ASP.NET MVC 3 tutorials for learning ASP.NET MVC. Following the instruction mentioned in this tutorial:

[http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-model's-data-from-a-controller](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/accessing-your-model%27s-data-from-a-controller)

MoviesController.cs was generated.  When I press F5 to run, the main webpage showed.  All is good.  But when I changed the URL according to instruction to `localhost:xxxx/Movies`, the browser stopped and the line of  code of the following function was highlighted with an Exception "Illegal characters in path" error.  The semicolon of the line was underscored in red.

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
      return View(db.Movies.ToList());
}
```

Although I am new to C# and ASP.Net, the statement seems right and consistence with the sample code in the tutorial.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: > localhost:xxxx/Movies I hope you did not add the xxxx in the url. This should be the port number of the webserver your Visual Studio makes use of. So your url should be something like `http://localhost:14564/Movies`. Can you place a breakpoint on the offending line and debug it if the former tip didn't help out?

Answer (score -1):

Add App_Data folder to your project..Hope it might Work. :)